# error: no member named 'async' in namespace 'std'

Tags: macos, c++11, clang++, stdasync, std-future

I know that `std::async` is a C++11 thing but I am pretty sure that my compiler has C++11 support.

```
#include <future>
using namespace::std;

void functionToRun() {
  // some code
}

int main() {
    auto x = 2; // throws warning warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    std::future<void> metricLoggerFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, functionToRun); // throws error  no member named 'async' in namespace 'std'
}
```

and if I use

```
std::future<void> metricLoggerFuture = async(std::launch::async, functionToRun); // error: use of undeclared identifier 'async'
```

Also g++ --version shows

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I have gone through the following,

- [No member named 'size' in namespace 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531258/no-member-named-size-in-namespace-std)
- [No Member named stoi in namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478687/no-member-named-stoi-in-namespace-std)

Also,

- OS: macOS Catalina
- This code is part of a bigger project (wrapper over TigerVNC) so there is a makefile, but since `auto` complies without any issues I don't think C++11 is the issue and hence passing `-std=c++11` in the `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` also doen't help.

Comment: Getting *throws warning warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]* means you are not using C++11.  Something is not correct in your makefile or compiler command.  Can you post that info?

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I was missing `std=c++11` at one of the places in the makefile. I can mark your answer has "Answer" if you post it separately :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not compiling with `c++11`, add `-std=c++11` (or later) to your compiler command line or makefile.